# SVM Separating hyperplane and its margin

Tags: matlab, svm

I am solving a classification problem using SVM specifically fitcsvm. I want to know how do I get the equation of the (a) separating hyperplane and (b) and equations of the margin.

My goal is to know whether a new sample (data_new, not added to the training set) is within the margin of separating hyperplane. BTW, im using gaussian kernel.

```
clc,clear; format compact; format shortG;
seed  = 1;
rng(seed);
r = sqrt(rand(100,1)); % Radius
t = 2*pi*rand(100,1);  % Angle
data1 = [r.*cos(t), r.*sin(t)]; % Points
r2 = sqrt(3*rand(100,1)+1); % Radius
t2 = 2*pi*rand(100,1);      % Angle
data2 = [r2.*cos(t2), r2.*sin(t2)]; % points
figure;
plot(data1(:,1),data1(:,2),'r.','MarkerSize',15); hold on
plot(data2(:,1),data2(:,2),'b.','MarkerSize',15)
ezpolar(@(x)1);ezpolar(@(x)2);
ylim([-2.5,2.5]); xlim([-2.5,2.5]); hold off
axis equal
```

[image]

```
data3 = [data1;data2];
theclass = ones(200,1);
theclass(1:100) = -1;
%Train the SVM Classifier
cl = fitcsvm(data3,theclass,'KernelFunction','rbf',...
    'BoxConstraint',Inf,'ClassNames',[-1,1]);
% Predict scores over the grid
d = 0.02;
[x1Grid,x2Grid] = meshgrid(min(data3(:,1)):d:max(data3(:,1)),...
    min(data3(:,2)):d:max(data3(:,2)));
xGrid = [x1Grid(:),x2Grid(:)];
[~,scores] = predict(cl,xGrid);
r_new = sqrt(1.0*rand(20,1)+0.5); % Radius
t_new = 2*pi*rand(20,1);      % Angle
data_new = [r_new.*cos(t_new), r_new.*sin(t_new)]; % points
% Plot the data and the decision boundary
figure;
h(1:2) = gscatter(data3(:,1),data3(:,2),theclass,'rb','.'); hold on
ezpolar(@(x)1); ezpolar(@(x)2);
h(3) = plot(data3(cl.IsSupportVector,1),data3(cl.IsSupportVector,2),'ko'); hold on
h(4) = gscatter(data_new(:,1),data_new(:,2),ones(20,1),'g','.');
contour(x1Grid,x2Grid,reshape(scores(:,2),size(x1Grid)),[0 0],'k');
legend(h,{'-1','+1','Support Vectors','New samples'}, Location="northeast");
axis equal
ylim([-2.5,2.5]); xlim([-2.5,2.5]); 
hold off
```

[image]

**How do I identify from the new samples added whether these samples are within the margin?**

Comment: What do you mean "withing the margin"? Do you want to just predict that point, and compare it to the known value?

Comment: @AnderBiguri What I mean by 'within the margin' is if L0 is the separating hyperplane, hyperplane L1: w.X+b < -1 for those with -1 labels and L2: w.X+b > 1 for those with +1 labels, points that are between hyperplanes L1 and L2. I just want to know whether the new added points is within the margin or not.

Comment: So do that? You literally described (and almost wrote) the code you need to produce in the comment to me, right? Check if point is in appropiate side of L1, and then the same for L2, if it sits in where you want it, then its in the margin no? something like (with appropiate variables): `in_margin= (w1*x+b1 >-1) && (w2*x+b2 <1)`, right?

Comment: @AnderBiguri This is the part I am not quite sure about. In matlab fitcsvm. it produces the support vectors and its corresponding labels.  Using the support vectors and calculating w.x+b might work for linear kernel but I am not sure with gaussian kernel.

Comment: I am not an expert in SVMs, so maybe I am wrong, but I don't see how the kernel affects the logic of prediction.